# Unhandel Server Error in Application. Compilation Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, compiler-errors

**Summary of the problem I am having:**

I have a button on a WebForm. that was previously working fine on a page named 'report.aspx.cs'. 
However the code suddenly not working and then when I try to run the system it has shows me error that says my system have and compilation error.

I have tried to find any misprint in my code but I have failed. for the record there was no person that have updated the code  for awhile, and the system is just working fine before this.

the error massage said that: httpexception was unhandled by user code in line 164.

**Error I am receiving:**

```
Server Error in '/reqapp' Application.
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.report_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Button6_Click2' and no extension method 'Button6_Click2' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.report_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:


Line 162:</asp:DropDownList>
Line 163:                &nbsp;&nbsp;
Line 164:                    <asp:Button ID="Button6" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700; text-align: left; font-size: x-small;" Text="VIEW BY COMPANY" Width="167px" Height="19px" OnClick="Button6_Click2" />
Line 165:                </td>
Line 166:                <td class="auto-style55"><strong>Completion Status</strong></td>

Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\reqapp\report.aspx    Line: 164 


Show Detailed Compiler Output:


c:\windows\system32\inetsrv> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /t:library /utf8output /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Services.Client\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Services.Client.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.Shared\13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.Shared.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Services.Design\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Services.Design.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\MySql.Data\v4.0_6.8.3.0__c5687fc88969c44d\MySql.Data.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reqapp\5aa10f0b\d9ed3f5f\assembly\dl3\366b917e\00cca943_0f02cf01\IdeaSparx.CoolControls.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms\13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reqapp\5aa10f0b\d9ed3f5f\assembly\dl3\4e9058bc\0063604e_0702cf01\IdeaSparx.CoolControls.Website.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reqapp\5aa10f0b\d9ed3f5f\assembly\dl3\4552db09\00b38fa0_eef8ce01\AjaxControlToolkit.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reqapp\5aa10f0b\d9ed3f5f\assembly\dl3\63008782\00cd8fc6_8f03ca01\mysql.web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reqapp\5aa10f0b\d9ed3f5f\App_global.asax.rwsymbbi.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine\13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reqapp\5aa10f0b\d9ed3f5f\assembly\dl3\3053726c\00bef0c7_3ff1ce01\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\log4net\1.2.10.0__692fbea5521e1304\log4net.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reqapp\5aa10f0b\d9ed3f5f\assembly\dl3\6226b886\00bef0c7_3ff1ce01\System.Spatial.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reqapp\5aa10f0b\d9ed3f5f\assembly\dl3\1ce7d6e3\00820180_2d26cf01\EntityFramework.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.Data.AdoDotNetInterop\13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.Data.AdoDotNetInterop.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reqapp\5aa10f0b\d9ed3f5f\assembly\dl3\c883d7f5\00bef0c7_3ff1ce01\Microsoft.Data.OData.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DataVisualization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DataVisualization.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reqapp\5aa10f0b\d9ed3f5f\assembly\dl3\4a6b2ea2\00ddfac1_3ff1ce01\HtmlAgilityPack.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reqapp\5aa10f0b\d9ed3f5f\assembly\dl3\1d4d86c9\09b464af_f6fed301\airod-protottype.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.Web\13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reqapp\5aa10f0b\d9ed3f5f\App_Web_r130cj02.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reqapp\5aa10f0b\d9ed3f5f\assembly\dl3\c72e3df1\008154cb_8f03ca01\mysql.visualstudio.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Linq.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reqapp\5aa10f0b\d9ed3f5f\assembly\dl3\c218e22a\00820180_2d26cf01\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reqapp\5aa10f0b\d9ed3f5f\assembly\dl3\049707a1\0060e647_8e03ca01\mysql.data.cf.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel\13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc\13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reqapp\5aa10f0b\d9ed3f5f\assembly\dl3\114aabd2\00ddfac1_3ff1ce01\AjaxMin.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers\13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Design\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Design.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Entity\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Web.Entity.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reqapp\5aa10f0b\d9ed3f5f\assembly\dl3\d3946e94\00820180_2d26cf01\mysql.data.entity.EF6.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reqapp\5aa10f0b\d9ed3f5f\assembly\dl3\b3e9e193\00bef0c7_3ff1ce01\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Entity\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Entity.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.ReportSource\13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reqapp\5aa10f0b\d9ed3f5f\assembly\dl3\365be372\0091bfc6_3ff1ce01\Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll" /out:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reqapp\5aa10f0b\d9ed3f5f\App_Web_k5ggx3zh.dll" /D:DEBUG /debug+ /optimize- /win32res:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reqapp\5aa10f0b\d9ed3f5f\k5ggx3zh.res" /w:4 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701;612;618 /warnaserror-  "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reqapp\5aa10f0b\d9ed3f5f\App_Web_k5ggx3zh.0.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reqapp\5aa10f0b\d9ed3f5f\App_Web_k5ggx3zh.1.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reqapp\5aa10f0b\d9ed3f5f\App_Web_k5ggx3zh.2.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reqapp\5aa10f0b\d9ed3f5f\App_Web_k5ggx3zh.3.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reqapp\5aa10f0b\d9ed3f5f\App_Web_k5ggx3zh.4.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reqapp\5aa10f0b\d9ed3f5f\App_Web_k5ggx3zh.5.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\reqapp\5aa10f0b\d9ed3f5f\App_Web_k5ggx3zh.6.cs"


Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.0.30319.17929

for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

c:\inetpub\wwwroot\reqapp\WebForm1.aspx(153,70): error CS1061: 'ASP.webform1_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Calendar1_SelectionChanged1' and no extension method 'Calendar1_SelectionChanged1' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.webform1_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\reqapp\WebForm1.aspx(153,70): error CS1061: 'ASP.webform1_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Calendar1_SelectionChanged1' and no extension method 'Calendar1_SelectionChanged1' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.webform1_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\reqapp\ReportGenerator.aspx(62,76): error CS1061: 'ASP.reportgenerator_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'ImageButton1_Click' and no extension method 'ImageButton1_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.reportgenerator_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\reqapp\ReportGenerator.aspx(62,76): error CS1061: 'ASP.reportgenerator_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'ImageButton1_Click' and no extension method 'ImageButton1_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.reportgenerator_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\reqapp\WebForm2.aspx(153,70): error CS1061: 'ASP.webform2_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Calendar1_SelectionChanged1' and no extension method 'Calendar1_SelectionChanged1' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.webform2_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\reqapp\WebForm2.aspx(153,70): error CS1061: 'ASP.webform2_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Calendar1_SelectionChanged1' and no extension method 'Calendar1_SelectionChanged1' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.webform2_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\reqapp\report.aspx(164,59): error CS1061: 'ASP.report_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Button6_Click2' and no extension method 'Button6_Click2' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.report_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\reqapp\report.aspx(164,59): error CS1061: 'ASP.report_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Button6_Click2' and no extension method 'Button6_Click2' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.report_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\reqapp\report.aspx(210,59): error CS1061: 'ASP.report_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Button8_Click' and no extension method 'Button8_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.report_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\reqapp\report.aspx(210,59): error CS1061: 'ASP.report_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Button8_Click' and no extension method 'Button8_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.report_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\reqapp\report.aspx(243,59): error CS1061: 'ASP.report_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Button4_Click' and no extension method 'Button4_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.report_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\reqapp\report.aspx(243,59): error CS1061: 'ASP.report_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Button4_Click' and no extension method 'Button4_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.report_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\reqapp\report.aspx(265,59): error CS1061: 'ASP.report_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Button7_Click' and no extension method 'Button7_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.report_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\reqapp\report.aspx(265,59): error CS1061: 'ASP.report_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Button7_Click' and no extension method 'Button7_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.report_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\reqapp\report.aspx(279,59): error CS1061: 'ASP.report_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Button3_Click' and no extension method 'Button3_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.report_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\reqapp\report.aspx(279,59): error CS1061: 'ASP.report_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Button3_Click' and no extension method 'Button3_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.report_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\reqapp\report.aspx(283,59): error CS1061: 'ASP.report_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Button5_Click' and no extension method 'Button5_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.report_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\reqapp\report.aspx(283,59): error CS1061: 'ASP.report_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Button5_Click' and no extension method 'Button5_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.report_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\reqapp\report.aspx(401,58): error CS1061: 'ASP.report_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Chart1_Load' and no extension method 'Chart1_Load' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.report_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\reqapp\report.aspx(401,58): error CS1061: 'ASP.report_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Chart1_Load' and no extension method 'Chart1_Load' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.report_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\reqapp\report.aspx(469,58): error CS1061: 'ASP.report_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'CrystalReportViewer1_Init' and no extension method 'CrystalReportViewer1_Init' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.report_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\reqapp\report.aspx(469,58): error CS1061: 'ASP.report_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'CrystalReportViewer1_Init' and no extension method 'CrystalReportViewer1_Init' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.report_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

**My code:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" BackColor="#FFFFCC" Height="31px" Width="185px" style="text-align: center">
    <asp:ListItem>--SELECT--</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>AIROD</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>NADI</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>INAYAH</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>AIROD TECHNO POWER</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>AIROD AEROSPACE TECHNOLOGY</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>AVIATION DESIGN CENTRE</asp:ListItem>   
    <asp:ListItem>AEROLOGICA</asp:ListItem> 
</asp:DropDownList>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:Button ID="Button6" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700; text-align: left; font-size: x-small;" Text="VIEW BY COMPANY" Width="167px" Height="19px" OnClick="Button6_Click2" />
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style55"><strong>Completion Status</strong></td>
                <td class="auto-style27">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" Height="32px" style="font-weight: 700" Width="148px" BackColor="#FFFFCC">
                        <asp:ListItem>--SELECT--</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>OPEN</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>CLOSED</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>PENDING</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
```

Comment: Make sure `Button6_Click2` exists in code behind. If exists do `Clean` and `Re-Build` solution https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tdasz7h.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `2`.

```
OnClick="Button6_Click2"
```

should be

```
OnClick="Button6_Click"
```

(Make sure `Button6_Click` exists in code-behind page.)